# AVR-HVPP with Arduino Mega2560 - Continously sending on SerialPort

Tags: arduino

I am trying to reprogram some scrambled ATtiny861A with the HVPP-version of ScratchMonkey.
I imported the sketch to my IDE (version 1.0.5) and compiled/uploaded that correctly.
With disabled debug-function, the TX-Led is lid continuously and some (much) data is transferred via serial port. Setting this to 115200 or 9600 baud didn't give any solution. All data is weird and there is no point to see what kind of data that could be.

So any ideas or suggestions on that, please?

PS: As I forgot to mention any detail, please ask, will give you all the info you need.

Comment: Are you using [this circuit](http://microtherion.github.io/ScratchMonkey/HVPP.html) with a 74HC595? Perhaps you can edit a traditional circuit diagram into your question using Ctrl+M?

Comment: Well, I use the ArduinoMega2560 and this gives me more ports as the standard Arduino. The wiring is straight foreward - no ´595 needed, because no serial/parallel converting needed (because of lack of ports on the standard arduino).

But I will add a wiring diagram. Also I believe that this is no wiring fault, because the "data stream" is coming out of the serial port(usb-serial to be precise). The scrambled data is also seen, when all wiring is disconnected. So I think this is a problem with the firmware/software.

Answer (score 1):

I tried now ScratchMonkey with an Arduino Nano.
So I see that CTRL2&CTRL3 is used as RX/TX.
I now want to change this two to another Port, perhaps A6 & A7.
As I use a ATTiny861/461 there is no need to use A6 / A7 in the normal
version for a attiny x61.

How can I change CTRL2 to A6 & CTRL3 to A7 ??
I looked in the sourcecode, but was lost a little bit... 8=)

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance...

Greetz......Detlef

Here is a small part of the schematics. As you see RX/TX is used as serial port:
btw. uC is ATMega328 not 168 as shown...
[image]

Comment: The code is in SMoHVPP.cpp. Look at the various layout models (the easiest of them is the Mega model, starting at line 196) and then create your own. I’m not sure if there is an #ifdef that can distinguish the Arduino Nano, but if there is, and you get your code to work, I’d be happy to receive a pull request :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I had forgotten a crucial detail: ADC6 and ADC7 are purely analog inputs, they cannot be used as digital pins in any fashion whatsoever (I suppose you could use one of them as a digital input by thresholding the analog reading, but I’d strongly advise against that). So I think you’re best off using the layout for standard Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit (as I hope I made clear in the documentation) that I have no personal experience with using a Mega2560 for ScratchMonkey.

For that reason, the documentation also does not show wiring diagrams etc in great detail, and the setup is designed to be quite different for the Mega2560 than it is with the Uno (no 74HC595, etc). The only documentation which exists is the last column in  [the SMoHVPP.h header](https://github.com/microtherion/ScratchMonkey/blob/master/SMoHVPP.h):

```
// PIN          Standard        Leonardo/Micro  Mega (1280 and 2560)
//
// D0-7           2-9             2-9          A8-A15                              
// HVRESET         10              10              10
// SVCC            A0              11              11
// RDY             12              12              12
// XTAL            A2              13              13
//
// MOSI 74595      11                                          
// SCK 74595       13                                           
// RCLK 74595      A1                       
//
// CTRL0                           A5              A0                              
// CTRL2                           RX (1)          A2
// CTRL3                           TX (0)          A3
// CTRL4                           A3              A4
// CTRL5                           A2              A5
// CTRL6                           A1              A6
// CTRL7                           A0              A7
```

Please let me know whether you get this to work, and if not, feel free to contact me by e-mail.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I will do some investigation on that problem and will keep you informed. Just for now I have to go further on with my main project, buying some more 861a´s for that. The "bricked" 861a´s will be repaired later. I think of creating a shield for that problem or a small pcb for some future problems with this uC´s. My standalone programmer is able to handle the 861´s & 861V´s, but not the 861A´s. This was the main fault, to end with 3 bricked 861A´s. Thanks once again - will contact you...